# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined. on loading a component that has an inner component

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

**create.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <base-input type="text" id="firstname" v-model="firstname"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
import BaseInput from 'BaseInput.vue'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            firstname: ''
        }   
    }
}   
</script>
```

**create.spec.js**

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Create from '/Create.vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

const wrapper = shallowMount(Create)
const vm = wrapper.vm
console.log(vm)
```

As you see, while loading the template using shallow Mount.
it throws the error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined   at
>   webpack:///node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5652:0
>   <- index.6fc62f9fc7f0f4a43161.js:9693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your `BaseInput` component to your export default. Now vue don't know what `BaseInput` is ([info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration), if you are using such as Babel or Webpack) . I also changed the data line because there need to be a `:` after data and function before the `()` ([example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)). If you do it like this it should work:

```
<script> 
import BaseInput from 'BaseInput.vue'
export default {
    components: {
       BaseInput 
    }
    data: function() {
        return {
            firstname: ''
        }   
    }
}   
</script>
```